# kaltura vpaas api, which property do I use to modify the co-editor or co-publsher

Tags: kaltura

```js
{ "adminTags": "", "allowedPartnerIds": "", "allowedPartnerPackages": "", "city": "", "country": "", "createdAt": 0, "deletedAt": 0, "description": "", "email": "", "fullName": "", "id": "", "indexedPartnerDataInt": 0, "indexedPartnerDataString": "", "language": "aa", "lastLoginTime": 0, "objectType": "KalturaUser", "partnerData": "", "partnerId": 0, "screenName": "", "state": "", "status": 0, "statusUpdatedAt": 0, "storageSize": 0, "tags": "", "thumbnailUrl": "", "updatedAt": 0, "userMode": 0, "zip": "", "attendanceInfo": "", "dateOfBirth": 0, "firstName": "", "gender": 0, "isAccountOwner": true, "isAdmin": true, "lastName": "", "loginEnabled": true, "password": "", "registrationInfo": "", "roleIds": "", "roleNames": "", "type": 0 }
```

I am pretty new to using the kaltura api. I want to dynamically adjust some of the objects via the api. For instance, the co-editor or co-partner, but I do not see in the object, which do I use or what actions in the documentations do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the property doesn't exist on the object (in your case the KalturaUser) then it is not updateable this object service (REST API).

You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.kaltura.com/api-docs/Enrich_and_Organize_Metadata).

I think you meant to update the co-editor / co-partner on the entry object - as each entry can have entitledUsersEdit / entitledUsersPublish fields which can contain list of user IDs. You can see example [here](https://developer.kaltura.com/api-docs/service/baseEntry/action/update).

So, after you have the user id from the object you have - you can use the baseEntry.update (from the link above) to set your user as co-editor/co-partner to the entry